# How to load my localhost (MapServer) on my website?

Tags: mapserver, ms4w

My localhost is http://localhost:8080/
and I am using MS4W 3.0.3 on this localhost for making the application as Hello world, single map, more than one layer map, and so on.

Now my folder is ms4w in C drive like:- c/ms4w  and I want to upload this to my own server on internet, I thought it would be a simple application, and not running application as like my localhost, but in my server not have MapServer, it should be if yes how to run MapServer on my website and I want to run application as that I create in my local host.

In my local host it's working fine, because its run on MapServer on my localhost.

Hence everybody known this problem please please help me how can I solve the problem, its urgent.

Comment: how have you done??? plz guide me i m new user

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid it's not that easy. You'll have to actually build/install MapServer on your server (assuming you have permission to do so) and then configure it all to work properly. You cannot just copy the folder from your MS4W folder to the server. A quick [Google search](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=installing%20mapserver&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a) will provide some starting points.

Comment: Ok,  Thank you very much for your valuable advice, I have done those was my problem,

Comment: You don't have to build MS4W, it's already built.  If your server is Windows you can just copy the whole installation across from your windows PC.  Obviously if your server is Linux based then this won't work.